# Lucene LongField error

Tags: java, eclipse, lucene, information-retrieval

I am getting this error when I copied `IndexFiles.java` (taken from the official lucene site) onto my Eclipse.

> The import org.apache.lucene.document.LongField cannot be resolved.

[image: The import org.apache.lucene.document.LongField cannot be resolved.]

I replaced `LongField` with `LegacyLongField` as I read somewhere that `LongField` is now renamed as `LegacyLongField`.

Comment: please post the error and at least the header of the class(es) -> Imports and package declaration

Comment: @Niton here is the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARdzL.png

Answer (score 1):

You are using propably newer version of Lucene. [LongField](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/LongField.html) is no more in org.apache.lucene.document package. You can use LegacyLongField, as you said, but it is better to use **[LongPoint](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/LongPoint.html)** instead as it is written in documentation of [LegacyLongField](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/LegacyLongField.html):

> **Deprecated**.
>
> Please use LongPoint instead